# SQL Calculate value with relation from table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with qualities of items which must meet must-have values. But the relations for checking is in a column.

Sample table:

| Item | Quality | ActualValue | Relation | MustValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | weight | 10 | < | 20 |
| A | volume | 5 | >= | 50 |
| B | volume | 12 | <= | 10 |

I look for a SELECT that brings up row 2 and 3, as in these rows the ActualValue is out of range of Relation & MustValue.

The result should be:

| Item | Quality | ActualValue | Relation | MustValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | volume | 5 | >= | 50 |
| B | volume | 12 | <= | 10 |

I expect there is something like
`WHERE ActualValue CONVERT(Relation+MustValue).`
Let's assume, Relation and MustValue are text fields and Relation is a valid SQL-relation.

I have no clue what function to search for.

How can be done this? I'm working on an Oracle Db system. Db model is given, I have only access for SELECT.

Comment: Columns ActualValue's and MustValue's data type?

Answer (score 0):

Nested CASE in the WHERE clause should do the job:

```
with data(Item, Quality, ActualValue, Relation, MustValue) as (
    select 'A', 'weight', 10, '<', 20 from dual union all
    select 'A', 'volume', 5, '>=', 50 from dual union all
    select 'B', 'volume', 12, '<=', 10 from dual -- union all
)
select * from data
where
    1 = 
    case relation
    when '<' then
        case when MustValue < ActualValue then 1 else 0 end
    when '>=' then
        case when MustValue >= ActualValue then 1 else 0 end
    when '<=' then
        case when MustValue <= ActualValue then 1 else 0 end
    end
;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have no clue what function to search for.

There is no function in SQL (comparable to `EVAL` in other languages) that will dynamically evaluate an expression as part of an SQL statement.

Instead, you can use `CASE` expressions and white-list the relationships you wish to use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CASE
       WHEN relation = '<'  THEN CASE WHEN actualvalue <  mustvalue THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       WHEN relation = '<=' THEN CASE WHEN actualvalue <= mustvalue THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       WHEN relation = '>'  THEN CASE WHEN actualvalue >  mustvalue THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       WHEN relation = '>=' THEN CASE WHEN actualvalue >= mustvalue THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       WHEN relation = '='  THEN CASE WHEN actualvalue =  mustvalue THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       WHEN relation = '!=' THEN CASE WHEN actualvalue != mustvalue THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       END = 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Item, Quality, ActualValue, Relation, MustValue) AS
SELECT 'A', 'weight', 10, '<',  20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'volume',  5, '>=', 50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'volume', 12, '<=', 10 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ITEM | QUALITY | ACTUALVALUE | RELATION | MUSTVALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | volume | 5 | >= | 50 |
| B | volume | 12 | <= | 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dn_G0--S)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use xmlquery to evaluate an expression:

```
with data(Item, Quality, ActualValue, Relation, MustValue) as (
    select 'A', 'weight', 10, '<', 20 from dual union all
    select 'A', 'volume', 5, '>=', 50 from dual union all
    select 'B', 'volume', 12, '<=', 10 from dual -- union all
)
select Item, Quality, ActualValue, Relation, MustValue
from (
    select Item, Quality, ActualValue, Relation, MustValue, MustValue || ' ' || Relation || ' ' || ActualValue
    as Expr from data
)
where xmlquery(Expr returning content).getStringVal() = 'true' 
;


A   volume  5   >=  50
B   volume  12  <=  10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own function to evaluate the expression:

```sql
WITH
    Function eval_expr(expr VarChar2) RETURN Number IS
        BEGIN
            -- returns 1 if True  |  0 if False  |  9 if error
            Declare 
                cmd     VarChar2(512) := 'Select Case When ' || expr || ' Then 1 Else 0 End From Dual' ;
                chk     Number;
            Begin
                execute immediate cmd InTo chk;
                RETURN chk;
            Exception 
                When Others Then RETURN 9;
            End;
        END eval_expr;
    tbl AS    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
        (   Select 'A' "ITEM", 'weight' "QUALITY", 10 "ACTUAL_VALUE", '<' "RELATION", 20 "MUST_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'A' "ITEM", 'volume' "QUALITY",  5 "ACTUAL_VALUE", '>=' "RELATION", 50 "MUST_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'B' "ITEM", 'volume' "QUALITY", 12 "ACTUAL_VALUE", '<=' "RELATION", 10 "MUST_VALUE" From Dual 
        )
--  M a i n   S Q L :
Select  * 
From    tbl
Where   eval_expr(ACTUAL_VALUE || RELATION || MUST_VALUE) = 0
      
/*    R e s u l t :
ITEM QUALITY ACTUAL_VALUE RELATION MUST_VALUE
---- ------  ------------ -------- ----------
A    volume             5 >=               50
B    volume            12 <=               10   */
```

This will check any valid expression that is used within Case expression's When clause including multiple conditions with AND/OR ...